# Unable to start the spring cloud eureka client in a service

Tags: spring, pom.xml, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-netflix

Unable to start the `spring cloud eureka` client in a service.

I'm using latest `spring 2.1.1` version.

Discovery Server started in a right fashion, but not the service client.

Unable trace out what causing the issue.... Below I have the configuration and the detailed log. please let me know in case of more information needed.

In the application class I have used the `@EnableDiscoveryClient`

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient
public class TrackerServiceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(JobTrackerServiceApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

In the `yml` I have given the `server discovery URL`.

```
spring:
  application:
    name: jtservice
eureka:
  client:
    service-url:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka
```

Given a detailed started up log

```
2018-12-28 01:18:57.283  WARN 15832 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.actuate.endpoint.EndpointId     : Endpoint ID 'service-registry' contains invalid characters, please migrate to a valid format.
2018-12-28 01:18:57.427  INFO 15832 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope     : BeanFactory id=52886b02-9a4c-31c8-82cc-0ae0241df564
2018-12-28 01:18:57.503  INFO 15832 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$1a87a789] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2018-12-28 01:18:57.528  WARN 15832 --- [  restartedMain] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource     : No URLs will be polled as dynamic configuration sources.
2018-12-28 01:18:57.528  INFO 15832 --- [  restartedMain] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource     : To enable URLs as dynamic configuration sources, define System property archaius.configurationSource.additionalUrls or make config.properties available on classpath.
2018-12-28 01:18:57.535  WARN 15832 --- [  restartedMain] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource     : No URLs will be polled as dynamic configuration sources.
2018-12-28 01:18:57.535  INFO 15832 --- [  restartedMain] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource     : To enable URLs as dynamic configuration sources, define System property archaius.configurationSource.additionalUrls or make config.properties available on classpath.
2018-12-28 01:18:58.664  WARN 15832 --- [  restartedMain] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jmxMBeanExporter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/endpoint/jmx/JmxEndpointAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.jmx.JmxEndpointExporter]: Factory method 'jmxMBeanExporter' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'serviceRegistryEndpoint' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/client/serviceregistry/ServiceRegistryAutoConfiguration$ServiceRegistryEndpointConfiguration.class]: Post-processing of merged bean definition failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.cloud.client.serviceregistry.endpoint.ServiceRegistryEndpoint] from ClassLoader [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@764c12b6]
2018-12-28 01:18:58.682  INFO 15832 --- [  restartedMain] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2018-12-28 01:18:58.703 ERROR 15832 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jmxMBeanExporter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/actuate/autoconfigure/endpoint/jmx/JmxEndpointAutoConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.jmx.JmxEndpointExporter]: Factory method 'jmxMBeanExporter' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'serviceRegistryEndpoint' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/client/serviceregistry/ServiceRegistryAutoConfiguration$ServiceRegistryEndpointConfiguration.class]: Post-processing of merged bean definition failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.cloud.client.serviceregistry.endpoint.ServiceRegistryEndpoint] from ClassLoader [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@764c12b6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:627) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:607) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1288) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1127) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:538) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:846) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:863) ~[spring-context-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546) ~[spring-context-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) [spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) [spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) [spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) [spring-boot-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at io.app.JobTrackerServiceApplication.main(JobTrackerServiceApplication.java:12) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.jmx.JmxEndpointExporter]: Factory method 'jmxMBeanExporter' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'serviceRegistryEndpoint' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/client/serviceregistry/ServiceRegistryAutoConfiguration$ServiceRegistryEndpointConfiguration.class]: Post-processing of merged bean definition failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.cloud.client.serviceregistry.endpoint.ServiceRegistryEndpoint] from ClassLoader [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@764c12b6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:622) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    ... 23 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'serviceRegistryEndpoint' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/cloud/client/serviceregistry/ServiceRegistryAutoConfiguration$ServiceRegistryEndpointConfiguration.class]: Post-processing of merged bean definition failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.cloud.client.serviceregistry.endpoint.ServiceRegistryEndpoint] from ClassLoader [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@764c12b6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1083) ~[spring-context-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.annotation.EndpointDiscoverer.createEndpointBean(EndpointDiscoverer.java:149) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.annotation.EndpointDiscoverer.createEndpointBeans(EndpointDiscoverer.java:136) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.annotation.EndpointDiscoverer.discoverEndpoints(EndpointDiscoverer.java:125) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.annotation.EndpointDiscoverer.getEndpoints(EndpointDiscoverer.java:119) ~[spring-boot-actuator-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.endpoint.jmx.JmxEndpointAutoConfiguration.jmxMBeanExporter(JmxEndpointAutoConfiguration.java:95) ~[spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.endpoint.jmx.JmxEndpointAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$af379275.CGLIB$jmxMBeanExporter$0(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.endpoint.jmx.JmxEndpointAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$af379275$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$e3054b35.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) ~[spring-core-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:363) ~[spring-context-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.endpoint.jmx.JmxEndpointAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$af379275.jmxMBeanExporter(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-actuator-autoconfigure-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [org.springframework.cloud.client.serviceregistry.endpoint.ServiceRegistryEndpoint] from ClassLoader [sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@764c12b6]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:686) ~[spring-core-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithLocalMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:546) ~[spring-core-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.buildLifecycleMetadata(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:207) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findLifecycleMetadata(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:189) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessMergedBeanDefinition(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:128) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessMergedBeanDefinition(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:297) ~[spring-context-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyMergedBeanDefinitionPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1044) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:550) ~[spring-beans-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    ... 45 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/http/ResponseEntity
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:668) ~[spring-core-5.1.3.RELEASE.jar:5.1.3.RELEASE]
    ... 52 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_181]
    ... 56 common frames omitted
```

FYI Discovery Server Log

```
i.r.app.DiscoveryServerApplication  : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2018-12-28 01:43:35.051  WARN 13244 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.actuate.endpoint.EndpointId     : Endpoint ID 'service-registry' contains invalid characters, please migrate to a valid format.
2018-12-28 01:43:35.364  INFO 13244 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope     : BeanFactory id=b41a245e-f8ca-34a8-84b9-ba7e1e8c0ab8
2018-12-28 01:43:35.499  INFO 13244 --- [  restartedMain] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration' of type [org.springframework.cloud.autoconfigure.ConfigurationPropertiesRebinderAutoConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$7773c593] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2018-12-28 01:43:36.257  INFO 13244 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8761 (http)
2018-12-28 01:43:36.287  INFO 13244 --- [  restartedMain] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
2018-12-28 01:43:36.287  INFO 13244 --- [  restartedMain] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/9.0.13
2018-12-28 01:43:36.298  INFO 13244 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener   : The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_181\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_181/bin/server;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_181/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_181/lib/amd64;C:\ProgramData\DockerDesktop\version-bin;C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin;C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\ProgramData\Boxstarter;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\SafeNet\Authentication\SAC\x64;C:\Program Files\SafeNet\Authentication\SAC\x32;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Program Files\PuTTY\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_181\bin;C:\workspace\apache-maven-3.5.3\bin;C:\workspace\apache-maven-3.5.3\bin;C:\HashiCorp\Vagrant\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\bin;C:\Users\z023401\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\z023401\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\workspace\web\sts-bundle\sts-3.9.5.RELEASE;;.]
2018-12-28 01:43:36.494  INFO 13244 --- [  restartedMain] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
2018-12-28 01:43:36.494  INFO 13244 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 2570 ms
2018-12-28 01:43:36.620  WARN 13244 --- [  restartedMain] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource     : No URLs will be polled as dynamic configuration sources.
2018-12-28 01:43:36.620  INFO 13244 --- [  restartedMain] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource     : To enable URLs as dynamic configuration sources, define System property archaius.configurationSource.additionalUrls or make config.properties available on classpath.
2018-12-28 01:43:36.635  INFO 13244 --- [  restartedMain] c.netflix.config.DynamicPropertyFactory  : DynamicPropertyFactory is initialized with configuration sources: com.netflix.config.ConcurrentCompositeConfiguration@cd0a551
2018-12-28 01:43:37.674  WARN 13244 --- [  restartedMain] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource     : No URLs will be polled as dynamic configuration sources.
2018-12-28 01:43:37.674  INFO 13244 --- [  restartedMain] c.n.c.sources.URLConfigurationSource     : To enable URLs as dynamic configuration sources, define System property archaius.configurationSource.additionalUrls or make config.properties available on classpath.
2018-12-28 01:43:37.899  INFO 13244 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Initializing ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2018-12-28 01:43:38.398  INFO 13244 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.d.a.OptionalLiveReloadServer       : LiveReload server is running on port 35729
2018-12-28 01:43:38.970  INFO 13244 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.a.e.web.EndpointLinksResolver      : Exposing 2 endpoint(s) beneath base path '/actuator'
2018-12-28 01:43:39.072  INFO 13244 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.c.n.eureka.InstanceInfoFactory       : Setting initial instance status as: STARTING
2018-12-28 01:43:39.124  INFO 13244 --- [  restartedMain] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Initializing Eureka in region us-east-1
2018-12-28 01:43:39.126  INFO 13244 --- [  restartedMain] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Client configured to neither register nor query for data.
2018-12-28 01:43:39.136  INFO 13244 --- [  restartedMain] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Discovery Client initialized at timestamp 1545941619134 with initial instances count: 0
2018-12-28 01:43:39.143  INFO 13244 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.c.n.e.s.EurekaServiceRegistry        : Registering application GBS-DISCOVERY-SERVER with eureka with status UP
2018-12-28 01:43:39.197  INFO 13244 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8761 (http) with context path ''
2018-12-28 01:43:39.199  INFO 13244 --- [  restartedMain] .s.c.n.e.s.EurekaAutoServiceRegistration : Updating port to 8761
2018-12-28 01:43:39.202  INFO 13244 --- [  restartedMain] i.r.app.DiscoveryServerApplication  : Started DiscoveryServerApplication in 7.455 seconds (JVM running for 8.927)
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>io.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>client-service</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>client-service</name>
    <description>client-service</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.RC2</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

</project>
```

Comment: Please attach dependencies you are using in the client application.

Comment: @AlexErohin Added the pom.xml

Answer (score 8):

Add the following

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is only a warning that can be ignored for now. See
[Endpoint ID 'service-registry' contains invalid characters #458](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-commons/issues/458)
 for further details.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue by importing project from older springboot version. Ensure to have same springboot, spring cloud and java versions as same as naming server.